# How to add keyboard accelerator to existing windows C# mixed mode DLL with patch?

Tags: c#, windows, dialog, accelerator

I have a application purchased from a vendor. but the vendor doesn't provide customized service. 
The application uses a C# mixed mode DLL to manage a data file selection. it creates a dialog, and you have to click a button control with caption "Load" to open a open file dialog. 
I am trying to add a keyboard accelerator to it, let's say I don't want to use mouse at all, so I want to add a keyboard accelerator "ALT+L" to open the open file dialog instead of click the button control.
I know If I have the source code, I can simply add a "&" before the "L" of the button's caption "Load". 
but for this case, I can only patch the DLL instead. so how should I do?
will patching the caption string from "Load" to "&Load" work?
I tried to patch the IL code, it will work, but the process is way too complicated and I have many controls to patch. plus this is a mixed mode C# DLL, the alternation of existing code is very complex.
Is there any way easier?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, this kind of questions is not suitable for stackoverflow. Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found the answer by creating a new C# project and experiment with the built application.
if you edit the string of the caption and add letter "&" before the hot hey you want, it will work. notice that the string is two bytes for each char.